# In Ubuntu-MATE, Is there a way to create keyboard shortcut for panel launcher icons?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, launcher, ubuntu-mate

On MATE panel (`Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS` specifically), there is this useful feature to drag and drop shortcuts for your favorite apps like firefox, nautilus, etc. But is there a way to launch them using keyboard hotkeys quickly?

I'm talking about these launcher icons on the top-left:

[image: Ubuntu MATE]

On Windows 10, for example, you can quickly start the second icon on the task-bar by clicking <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc. Does MATE have a similar shortcut?

Comment: Sure, its 18.04 LTS (Bionic). I'll make the edit.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to use the "Mutiny" mode via Mate Tweaks > Panel. There, just like in Ubuntu's Unity, you'll be able to use Super+1 to launch the first item, Super+2 to launch the second and so on. I'm not sure that feature is available with the other panels (including the one in your image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to attach a keyboard to launch the icons on your panel. However, you can create such shortcuts using "Keyboard Shortcuts" in the settings. From a practical user point of view, the effect will be the same. The only issue is that these shortcuts will not automatically update if you reposition a launcher on your panel - you will need to edit your keyboard shortcuts to reflect changes on your panel.